# AzureAD Graph API - Getting the delta of users in a group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are using the MS Graph API and would like to check the changes of users in a certain group. Currently we get the users via this query:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/members

This is how we retrieved the delta of the group:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id eq 'GroupId'&$select=members

Now my question would be if there is a way to relate this delta only to users in this group.

I can see a result when I add or delete a user from the group, but I need a result, even if the name, street or something else getting changed.

I would be very grateful for any feedback.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

There are limited [***supported-resources***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources) to query delta , which includes groups, Users etc but not particularly for member and its properties of one such group.

I tried to query for members this way and got unsupported error

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxxx/members/delta?$select=displayName,jobTitle,mobilePhone
```

[image]

But you may retrieve members of all groups whose membership changes, such as when users are added or removed /( updated ) as you knew .

I’ve tried this way ***with `prefer: return=minimal` 'header' to return only the object properties that have changed since the last round***.  and got removed and updated users but their properties that changed are not listed .We may need to copy the user Id that changed and query for that using [***user-delta***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'xxxx-xxxxa-xxxxx52eb'&$select=members+&$select=displayName
```

(or)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'xxxx2-xxxxxxxxeb'&$expand=members
```

[image]

To filter separately for other properties like jobTitle ,its not valid .

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'xxxxxxxxxxxx2-xxx'&$expand=members+&$select=displayName,jobTitle,mobilePhone
```

You can raise a [***Support request***](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UserDetailsMenuBlade/supportRequest) for the same.

**References** :

1. [delta-query-groups | Microsoft Docssupported-resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups)
2. [microsoft-graph-issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3530)